# Eventbus (greenrobot) event when subscriber is unregistered

Tags: java, android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

I have a requirement where a service needs to be able to cancel a network request when all subscribers have unregistered from a specific event. I am using Greenrobot EventBus and as far as I can tell there is nothing built in that will send an event whenever someone unregisters.
I was thinking that I could override the EventBus's unregister method and post an 'UnsubscribedEvent' whenever it is called. The service can then listen to this event and when it receives it it can call hasSubscriberForEvent to check whether it should cancel the request. Does this sound reasonable or does anyone have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What you specified in the question should work just fine.

Alternatively, to avoid complications of overriding the library's methods and messing things up unknowingly you could go like this:

1. Keep a counter that would be tracking registered subscribers
2. Increment/decrement the counter as and when there are new subscriptions or unregistering (use a method)
3. Inside the counter tracking method, check if the value counter is `0` and cancel the network request (if ongoing)